# How to return a component and a function, or what's the alternative?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[React] What is the "way" to send/share a function between components?

Better explained in (useless) code

- Here I have no problem since everything is in the same component (https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ishizaka-uzlik)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState();
  const letbook = () => setBookmarks("hello");

  const Card = () => <div onClick={letbook}>hey</div>;

  const MyCom = () => {
    return <div><Card /></div>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={letbook}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <MyCom />
      <div>{bookmarks}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- But then, if now I want to split code, how do I do this? The problem is how to share `letbook` (this code doesn't work)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const Card = () => <div onClick={letbook}>hey</div>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={letbook}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <MyCom />
      <div>{bookmarks}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const MyCom = () => {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState();
  const letbook = () => setBookmarks("hello");

  return (
    <div>
      <Card />
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

- I could use a hook that returned the component and the function

```js
const [letbook, MyCom] = useMyCom
```

But this is not recommended (https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9yq1l8/how_do_you_feel_about_a_hook_returning_components/)

- Then I can use a hook and a component, as with the following code, but the code itself seems obfuscated to me, to a point that I doubt whether I should split the code or not

Unless (and this is the question) whether there is a smarter way to do this

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks, letbook] = useMyCom();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={letbook}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <MyCom card={props => <Card letbook={letbook} />} />
      <div>{bookmarks}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Card = ({letbook}) => <div onClick={letbook}>hey</div>;

const useMyCom = () => {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState();
  const letbook = () => setBookmarks("hello");
  return [bookmarks, setBookmarks, letbook];
};

const MyCom = ({ letbook, card }) => <div>{card(letbook)}</div>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your component to reuse it is definitely a good idea. But make sure your are using and manipulate a single state in the same file an pass it as props. Also, it is important that you avoid to re-render your child component. Only when your main component change props that are necessary to re-render your child component.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";

const MyCom = memo(props => {
  return <div>{props.bookmarks}</div>;
});

export default function App() {
  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState();
  const letbook = () => setBookmarks("hello");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={letbook}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <MyCom bookmarks={bookmarks} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated the question improving the example -- also, why do you need memo in your example?

Comment: memo is used to prevent to re-render when your props values don't change. This is very important for performance.

Comment: Yes, but (in your example) being the component outside the main component, is memo necessary?

Comment: Test this code with and without memo. check the console and let me know what is the difference. https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-shaw-jjhj9

Comment: Thanks for the example :) I see that any of the two buttons are actually rendering everything without the memo, thanks!